# How to filter running in VLC video stream on commandline?

Tags: windows, command-line, vlc-media-player

I easily can broadcast my webcam with VLC using command lines like this (I use Windows):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" -vvv -I --dshow-vdev="Logitech QuickCam Express / Go" dshow:// --sout
```

When I paste command into CMD and hit enter it starts streaming (all is fine - I can play it).

How can I now for example add brightness or any other filter to that stream from the commandline?

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the filters by doing `--video-filter=<STRING>` , where `<STRING>` is your filter. So in this case, `--video-filter=adjust` and then your switches to control brightness.